# Не получается верно записать строку в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

делаю задание по книге
Гостевая книга: напишите цикл while, который в цикле запрашивает у пользователей
имена При вводе каждого имени выведите на экран приветствие и добавьте строку с со-
общением в файл с именем guest_book txt Проследите за тем, чтобы каждое сообщение
размещалось в отдельной строке файла
Вот моя попытка решить эту задачу.

```
print("Для выхода из программы введите quit")
name = ''

while name != 'quit':
    name = input("Введите ваше имя: \n")
    if name != 'quit':
        print(f"Привет {name}")
        break
with open(filename,"a") as file_object:
    file_object.write(name + "\n" )
```

Файл не сохраняет результат в отформатированном виде пробовал использовать конструкцию `'f{name}\n'`
Также после одной введённой строки выдаёт ошибку
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'Evgen' is not defined**
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Всё должно работать, но только у вас один раз только сработает ввод. Уберите `break` и сделайте у вывода в файл такой же сдвиг как у привета.

Comment: А что за Evgen такой, откуда он тут вообще - совершенно непонятно

Comment: @CrazyElf "Evgen" Строка вводимая мною с клавиатуры, да спасибо уже решил проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print("Для выхода из программы введите quit")

# Спсиок куда будут добавляться строки
lines = []

while (name := input("Введите ваше имя: \n")) != 'quit':
    # Формируем строку
    line = f"Привет {name}"
    # Печатаем
    print(line)
    # Добавляем в список
    lines.append(
        line
    )
with open('guest_book.txt', "w") as file_object:
    # Объединяем символом перевода строки элемнты спска строк
    # И записываем их в файл
    file_object.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в начале программы в условии **if** стоит **break**. После него код не выполняется когда вы вводите что угодно кроме **quit**

```
filename_directory = r'Eric Matthes - Python Crash Course\Chapter 10\Files\Exercise_file_10.4.txt'

while True:
    name = input('Please tel me your name: ')
    with open(filename_directory, 'a') as file_obbject:
        if name == "stop":
            print('Sessions are over')
            break
        else:
            file_obbject.write(f"{name.title()}\n")
            print(f"Hello, {name.title()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = 'guest_book.txt'
a = 0
while a < 5 :          # так потому что не охота писать if 'quit' == break 
   a += 1              # каждая итерация + 1 к 'a', потом while прервется
   name_guest = input("Введите ваше имя: ")
   print(f'Привет, {name_guest}!')
   with open(filename, 'a') as file_object:
       file_object.write(f'{name_guest} \n')
```

написал аргумент  'а'

у меня 'w' перезаписывал прошлые итерации. аргумент
'а', как я понял, "принимает всё, без перезаписывания.